# How to check if a login exists on SQL Server level … different behaviour between databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have something very strange happening. I need to create a user from within my application and have crated a stored procedure for that.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_CREATEUSER]
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @LoginName NVARCHAR(50)
, @Password  NVARCHAR(50)
  WITH EXECUTE AS 'WMSApplicatieAdmin'
AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  PRINT 'P_CREATEUSER'

  -- Insert statements for procedure here
  DECLARE @DBNAME NVARCHAR(128);

  SELECT @DBNAME = DB_NAME( );

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

  IF (@Password IS NULL)
  BEGIN
    SET @Password = '';
  END


  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name
        FROM master.sys.server_principals
        WHERE name = @LoginName)
  BEGIN
    PRINT '@loginname = ' + COALESCE( @LoginName, 'NULL' )
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @LoginName + '] WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @Password + ''', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' + @DBNAME + '], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF';
    PRINT @SQL
    EXECUTE (@SQL);
    PRINT 'Created Login'
  END

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name
        FROM sys.database_principals
        WHERE name = @LoginName)
  BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE USER [' + @LoginName + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @LoginName + ']';
    PRINT @SQL
    EXECUTE (@SQL);
    PRINT 'Created User'
  END
END
```

Now, normally this should be working nicely. I've tested it on our Development database and it works fine. On the production database it doesn't however. The strange thing is that the SELECT from server_principals returns different results on the DEV database than it does on the PRD database.

On my PRD database it only returns the following records :

```
SELECT name
  FROM master.sys.server_principals

name
sa
public
sysadmin
securityadmin
serveradmin
setupadmin
processadmin
diskadmin
dbcreator
bulkadmin
```

On the DEV Database though it does correctly return the set given above, but also all logins created. I have no idea what could be causing this problem or what I am doing wrong, so I hope someone here could help me out.

**UPDATE**

I have the immersion that it has something to do with an Application role. Even in SQL Server I only get the 10 listed items when using the following statement :

```
DECLARE @MyCoockie VARBINARY(MAX)

EXECUTE sys.sp_setapprole @rolename = 'WMSApplicatie' /* SYSNAME */
                        , @password = @MyPassword /* SYSNAME */
                        , @encrypt = 'None' /* VARCHAR(10) */
                        , @fCreateCookie = 1 /* BIT */
                        , @cookie = @MyCoockie OUT

SELECT NAME
  FROM sys.server_principals

EXECUTE sys.sp_unsetapprole @cookie = @MyCoockie
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try with sa or admin login.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your production server has additional security which prevents your login from seeing the user names. This would be normal for a production server. There is probably a process to have these logins added to production.

Comment: Hi … both databases are on the same SQL Server. When looking at the SQL Server I can clearly see all the users.

Comment: I notice that it might have something to do with an Application Role which is getting set when starting th application :